# Fast full-text search using String.IndexOf or MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, search, full-text-search

I have a situation where I need a super fast full-text wildcard search.

Previously I was using ONLY a SQL stored procedure that would perform a search on tables with multiple joins and using a query with `LIKE '%searchTerm%'` however it was very slow over a few million records.

I have tried full-text indexing and searching in SQL, however, that seems to not work since it breaks on words, but I need to search the middle of strings.

Changing to a new SQL stored procedure that concatenates all of the search fields into one string, and returns that with another column of the object ID -- and then caching that entire object as a `List<>` in C# (specifically as a static object within the `AppPool`) and using logic that checks `IndexOf()` of the search string seems to have increased the performance substantially *(from about 10 seconds to about 100 milliseconds)*.

My concern is whether or not this is a bad approach, or if there is perhaps an even better approach?

The new SQL stored procedure that creates the search string to associate with an object ID is as follows;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_GetLookupTable]
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        ObjectId,
        (Name + ' ' + OtherName + ' ' + ep.SomethingElse + ISNULL(

            (

            SELECT
                    ' ' + twl.SomeBindingName
                FROM
                    TableWithLotsOfBindings twl
                WHERE 
                    twl.ObjectId = e.ObjectId
                FOR XML PATH('')

            )

        , '')) AS SearchString,
        ep.LastActionDateTime AS OrderDate
    FROM
        ObjectTable e
        INNER JOIN ObjectMetaData ep ON ep.ObjectId = e.ObjectId
END 
GO
```

This then gets loaded into a `List<>` with a model that has the `ObjectId` and `SearchString`.  I am then persisting this into a `static` property within a search `class`, and then keep track of a last load `DateTime` and recycle it every 10 minutes or so.

I originally also saved this to a distributed in-memory cache, however, performance was very poor serializing and transmitting the data.

```
private static readonly List<GlobalSearchLookupModel> _CachedSearchLookupModel = new List<GlobalSearchLookupModel>();
private static DateTime _CacheSearchLookupModelDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

List<GlobalSearchLookupModel> lookupModels = _CachedSearchLookupModel.Value;

if (lookupModels == null)
{
   lookupModels = SqlClass.SearchLookupTable();
   _CachedSearchLookupModel.Value.Clear();
   _CachedSearchLookupModel.Value.AddRange(lookupModels);
   _CachedSearchLookupModelDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

if (_CacheSearchLookupModelDateTime.AddMinutes(10) <= DateTime.UtcNow)
{
   _CachedSearchLookupModelDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
   BackgroundTaskHelper.StartBackgroundTask(
   "Pre-Load Global Search Lookup Table",
   () =>
   {
      DateTime asyncPreloadStartDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
      _CachedSearchLookupModel.Value.Clear();
      _CachedSearchLookupModel.Value.AddRange(SqlClass.SearchLookupTable());
      _CachedSearchLookupModelDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

   });
}

List<Int64> ids = lookupModels
   .Where(l => l.SearchString.IndexOf(searchTerms, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
   .OrderByDescending(l => l.OrderDate)
   .Select(l => l.ObjectId)
   .Distinct()
   .Take(maxReturn)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use non-SQL solutions which specialize in full-text searches? Such as Elasticsearch or pure Lucene? Also, have a look into Bitmap Index, you can greatly speed up things if you index ngrams and you text is natural (no hashes, garbage)

Comment: I haven't tried ElasticSearch or anything else yet.  I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate on why full text index doesnt work?

Comment: @Steve the full-text index didn't work because it wouldn't search in the middle of a `String`.  The only method in SQL that worked was using a query with `LIKE '%term%'`

Comment: @Sivart im pretty sure full text index can search in the middle of a string. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Steve,  when I attempted this earlier, one of the data elements was "AppleSauce" and searching for "sauce" or "ple" didn't return any results, but searching for "app" did.  I could never get it to search in the middle of a "word."

Answer (score 1):

There is no such solution available in any modern SQL database that I am aware of. They are simply not designed for use cases such as yours.

You really need to have a look at solutions like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/) or [Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/?&OCID=AID758577_SEM_Kl1sCcDe&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&dclid=CjgKEAiA14TjBRD3rbXntvK7-jkSJABI7JkPETIsNze1LhOwz1xB9QAZ9VHXD_T52-G6rnzIRICNvfD_BwE) for such a solution, even those require you to use special constructs and filters to achieve pure wildcard search functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build your own searchindex in SQL using the following idea:

Let's say your table is

`MyTable(Id bigint Primary Key, Text nvarchar(max))`

, where `Text` is the column you want to search in.

Then build a table

```
IndexTable(TextIndex nvarchar(max) Primary Key, Id bigint)
```

, with `Id` a foreign key to `MyTable`.

Now you populate that table with **all suffixes** of the texts contained in MyTable.

You can now rewrite your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Text LIKE '%searchTerm%'

to

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM IndexTable WHERE TextIndex LIKE 'searchTerm%')
```

(This query could also be written with a join, but then could result in duplicates)

This should be an efficient query as `LIKE 'searchTerm%'` can use the PK-Index of the IndexTable.

And as final note, you can keep that table up to date with triggers.